# How to increase the buffer size of the 'output window' in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I build my C++ project with *Show Includes* option enabled.

I want to create a graph of the included files, so I copy all the text of the *output window*. However, compilation produces so many lines, that after a certain limit, they are clipped.

I have noticed that this limit is ~59 Mbytes.

Is there a way to increase this limit, or set it to infinity? Could I at least redirect this output straight into a text file, instead of copying & pasting the text from *output window*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio generates a log file in the output directory.

Everything should be there.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 doesn't seem to generate any logs in the output directory of C# projects.

Comment: The original question was for C++ and visual 2010

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but the accepted answer is lacking...

To better answer the OP's question -- You can view and configure the build output as shown in this MS article:
[How to: View, save, and configure build log files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-view-save-and-configure-build-log-files?view=vs-2019)

Here is an excerpt:

> After you build a project in the Visual Studio IDE, you can view
> information about that build in the Output window. By using this
> information, you can, for example, troubleshoot a build failure.
>
> For C++ projects, you can also view the same information in a log file
> that's created and saved when you build a project.
>
> ...

> ### To view the build log file for a C++ project

> 1. In Windows Explorer or File Explorer, open the following file (relative to the project root folder): Release\<ProjectName>.log or Debug\<ProjectName>.log

Comment: How do you get a log for C# projects?